# What’s the Jewish equivalent to The Art of War?

Tags: army-military-war

I know from Parashas Vayishlach, there is a reference to how a Jew should prepare for war. Yaakov prays and sends Esau a large gift to appease him.

Where can I find more sources on how a Jew fights a war?

Comment: Possibly a lost book known as Sefer HaYashar https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Samuel.1.18?lang=bi

Comment: You can take a look at Rambam - https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars?tab=contents

Comment: The Torah is pretty clear that success in war has to do with one's faith in Hashem. The tactics and strategy are up to the commander, generally speaking. Similarly, the Torah commands us to build a fence to protect people from falling, but does not include instructions on construction methods. Just get the fence built.